# How hard is this climb and how long should i be taking?

Tags: climbing

This was my first attempt at this route on my several year old Avanti Giro 1.0. Ive just started riding again after quite a few years and am h

https://www.mapmyrun.com/workout/3796895674

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.se David, normally this type of question is too broad and opinionated to be answered properly so I expect it may get closed soon unless you can edit the question to not be so opinionated, also your profile on mapmyrun is set to friends only so we cant see your workout.

Comment: One way to make the question less opinionated is to show the climb (eg with coordinates or a screen shot). And ask how fast riders typically are, how far the best are. Or ask for quantifiable data like what speed at what power per weight (W/kg).

Comment: You could look to see if it's a segment on Strava, which might give you some idea of how how long it typically takes people to get up there. But, honestly, there's no answer to "how long _should_ it take?" That depends on your fitness, ability, equipment, the weather, ...

Comment: @David - you forgot to mention the most variable one (for me anyway) - Motivation.  :)

Comment: Frankly - it doesn't matter how long it should take.  What matters is how long you took the first time, and whether your subsequent efforts improve on that time.

Answer (score 2):

A common measure of fitness in the pro peloton is watts per kilogram, or how many watts of power can you generate per kilogram of body weight for a 1 hour effort. This is more or less a direct translation into your climbing prowess.

The "[magic number](https://datacranker.com/cycling-power-to-weight-ratio-calculator/)" for pro racers is 6 watts per kilogram. I would say that for a recreational rider anything over 2 watts per kilogram is pretty good.

You can get some estimate of the power required for a climb via various online [calculators](http://bikecalculator.com/). They are at best a good guess, but for climbs without headwinds at speed less than 20 kph, reasonably accurate.

These numbers will not be super accurate, but will give you some idea of what is typical.

Comment: is that 6 W/kg at FTP? or max?

Comment: For a 1 hour effort, very few pros have ever achieved that and the one's that have claimed it don't exactly have the cleanest records.

Comment: Sure, but when they achieved that number, what kind of time period was being considered?

Comment: 6 W/Kg is for a 1 hour effort, and is typically what would be required to podium in a grand tour